# How to use maybe monad inside another monad?

Tags: haskell, happstack

I have this code (inside happstack, but could be just the IO monad):

```
accountHandler conn = do
  sessionId <- optional $ readCookieValue "sessionId"

  case sessionId of
    Nothing -> seeOther ("/" :: String) $ toResponse ()
    Just s  -> do
      result <- loggedInUserId conn s

      case result of
        Just userId -> seeOther ("/account/" ++ unUserId userId) $ toResponse ()
        Nothing -> seeOther ("/" :: String) $ toResponse ()
```

I want to remove the nested case statements and write something like:

```
accountHandler conn = do

  let action = do
                sessionId <- optional $ readCookieValue "sessionId"
                userId    <- loggedInUserId conn sessionId

                return $ seeOther ("/account/" ++ userId)

  maybe (seeOther ("/" :: String)) id action $ toResponse ()
```

... but userId ends up as a type of `Maybe String` rather than just `String`. How can I evaluate the nested `do` block using the maybe monad? (I would also accept a different refactoring that removes the nested cases.)

**UPDATE: Below is a generic, though contrived, version of the same problem:**

```
module Main where

getAnswer expected = do
  l <- getLine

  if l == expected
    then return $ Just l
    else return $ Nothing

main = do
  a <- getAnswer "a"

  case a of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "nope"
    Just x -> do
      b <- getAnswer x

      case b of
        Nothing -> putStrLn "nope"
        Just _ -> putStrLn "correct!"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, with your generic example I could do something with `Control¸Monad.Transformers`. This allows you to create a stack of monads. You can check it out here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html
You can apply MaybeT to everything of type `IO (Maybe a)`  and then do all the computations in the inner do block and then check for Nothing at the end.

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe


getAnswer expected = MaybeT $ do
       l <- getLine
       if l == expected
       then return $ Just l
       else return $ Nothing

main = do
    y <- runMaybeT $ do a <- getAnswer "a"
                        b <- getAnswer a
                        return b
    case y of Nothing  -> putStrLn "failure"
              (Just _) -> putStrLn "correct"
```

Another version using `liftIO` and the `Alternative` type class:

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Applicative


getAnswer expected = MaybeT $ do
  l <- getLine
  if l == expected
    then return $ Just l
    else return $ Nothing

main = do
    _ <- runMaybeT $ do a <- getAnswer "a"
                        b <- getAnswer a
                        liftIO $ putStrLn "correct" 
                   <|> do liftIO $ putStrLn "failure"
    return ()
```

But using many lift operations is not very elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add to MoFu's answer that once you have `MaybeT IO`, you can use the full power of its `MonadPlus` instance. For example, if you need to check that some condition holds, use `guard` or `mfilter`. So you can write:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

getAnswer :: (MonadPlus m, MonadIO m) => String -> m String
getAnswer expected = mfilter (== expected) $ liftIO getLine
```

It's type is very generic, it works for any monad that is `MonadPlus` and `MonadIO`. This is handy if you decide to modify your monad stack later. But we could also use more specific type `(MonadIO m) => String -> MaybeT m String`.

For extracting a `MaybeT IO` value from your inner computation I'd suggest to write a variant of `fromMaybe` for `MaybeT`:

```
fromMaybeT :: (Monad m) => m a -> MaybeT m a -> m a
fromMaybeT onFail = maybe onFail return <=< runMaybeT
```

It extracts the result with `runMaybeT`. If it's `Just`, just return it, otherwise run `onFail` action.

Combined together, we get:

```
main = fromMaybeT (putStrLn "nope") $ do
  a <- getAnswer "a"
  b <- getAnswer a
  liftIO $ putStrLn "correct!"
```